# Search result breaks delete action

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a page where I display campaigns.  I wont show all the code but the basic structure is like so

```
@foreach ($campaigns as $campaign)
    {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id))) !!}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            @if (!empty($campaign->campaignName))
                <div class="panel-heading campaignPanelHeading">
                    <h4>{{ $campaign->campaignName  }}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <a href="{{ route('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteCampaign" data-method="delete" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

If I try to delete an item, the following is triggered.

```
$("#deleteCampaign").on("submit", function(){
    return confirm("Do you want to delete this item?");
});
```

Now on this page where I display all campaigns I have a search box.  You start typing and an autocomplete list displays.  When you select an option, this is triggered

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/returnDataForCampaigns",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "html",
        data: {
            value : ui.item.value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.container').html(data.html);
            $('.selectpicker').select2();
        }
    });
},
```

This essentially calls a function which gets the selected Campaign, and injects it into the following partial

```
@if(!empty($campaign))
    {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline delete', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id))) !!}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        @if (!empty($campaign->campaignName))
            <div class="panel-heading campaignPanelHeading">
                <h4>{{ $campaign->campaignName  }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="{{ route('campaigns.destroy', $campaign->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteCampaign" data-method="delete" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <span class="glyphicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    Delete
                </a>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

Finally, this data is then injected into the page's container.  Now this all works fine.  When I check the source after it has been injected everything looks correct.

I have 2 other buttons which I removed above which show or edit the campaign, these work fine.  The thing that is not working is the delete button for the searched campaign.  For some reason when I click this it goes to the campaigns show page.  This button works when I display all campaigns, its only when search is performed it does not work.

I have checked the code for the delete button for when all campaigns are displayed vs a searched campaign.  Everything is the same apart from the Javascript which has been applied to the delete button when all campaigns are shown as well as some hidden inputs

```
<a data-token="dsfsd" data-method="delete" id="deleteCampaign" class="btn btn-danger" onclick=" if ($(this).hasClass('action_confirm')) { if(confirm($(this).data('message') || &quot;Are you sure you want to do this?&quot;)) { $(this).find(&quot;form&quot;).submit(); } } else { $(this).find(&quot;form&quot;).submit(); }">
     Delete                                  
<form style="display:none" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/campaigns/43">
    <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="_method">
    <input type="hidden" value="dsfsd" name="_token">
</form>
</a>
```

This is a searched button

```
<a data-token="dsfsd" data-method="delete" id="deleteCampaign" class="btn btn-danger" href="http://localhost:8000/campaigns/9">
    Delete
</a>
```

So my main question is why this may be happening?  I would also like to try and find out why the searched version of the delete button also takes you to the show page?

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your delete jquery code:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#deleteCampaign", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return confirm("Do you want to delete this item?");
});
```

Its because you are adding content after DOM load.

Comment: Result seems to be the same.